# Linking CSS to HTML File

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link my CSS file to the HTML but it doesn't seem to work and I do not see any errors on the syntax

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project Website Styling.css">
```

[This is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d6tA.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have those spaces in your file name. Separate it with hyphens. If you can't change the file name, then add `%20` where the spaces are in that code above.

`href="Project%20Website%20Styling.css"`